# How to create a JSON file in a particular format in Java

Tags: java, json, arraylist, format

I am trying to write a JSON file using Java in a particular format. For example: let's suppose I like to get the JSON file written in the following format:

```
{
"resource":[{"name":"Node1"}],

"literals":[{"literal":"A", "B", "C", "D"}]
}
```

As you may notice, in `resource`, I would like to write strings in there and in `literals`, I like to have an arraylist of strings. Here are my Java codes:

```
public void writeJSON() {

public ArrayList<String> literals  = new ArrayList<String>();  

literals.add("A");
literals.add("B");
literals.add("C");
literals.add("D");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonObject.put("name", resources.getResource());

resources.setLiterals(literals);

jsonObject.put("literal", resources.getLiterals());

try {

    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/Documents/sample.json");
    file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
    file.flush();
    file.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Here is the Java file where I set and get values for the JSON file:

```
public class Resources {

String resource;
ArrayList<String> literals;
public Resources()
{

}
public void setResource(String resource) 
{  
        this.resource = resource;
}  

public String getResource()
{
    return resource;
}
public void setLiterals(ArrayList<String> literals) 
{  
  this.literals = literals;  
}
public ArrayList<String> getLiterals() 
{  
      return literals;  
}  
}
```

Could anyone please help me how to create a JSON file based on the format provided above. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You evidently are already doing _something_ trying to generate JSON. How does it not do what you want?

Comment: `{"source":"A", "B", "C", "D"}` this is not valid Json.

Comment: I generated that file but unfortunately not the format I want. It does not show me "resource" and "literals". Any idea how to generate that particular format?

Comment: You cannot generate "that particular format" using JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start that `Json` you are trying to create is invalid.
This is what you have:

```
{
"resource":[{"name":"Node1"}, 
            {"name":"Node2"}],

"literals":[{"source":"A", "B", "C", "D"},
            {"source":"E", "F", "G", "H"}]
}
```

As you can see `resource` looks OK - i.e. it is an object that contains `List` of objects.
On the other hand `literals` is an object that contain a `List` of what? since not `{"source":"A", "B", "C", "D"}` nor `{"source":"E", "F", "G", "H"}` is a valid `Json`.

Figure out this first, then update your `java` code and we will go from there.

If this: `{"resource":[{"name":"Node1"}],"literals":[{"literal":["A","B","C","D"]}]}` is desirable, then you can achieve that in the following way(I will use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)):

```
JsonWriter jsonWriter = null;
try {
    jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("test.json"));
    jsonWriter.beginObject();
    jsonWriter.name("resource");
    jsonWriter.beginArray();
    jsonWriter.beginObject();
    jsonWriter.name("name");
    jsonWriter.value("Node1");
    jsonWriter.endObject();
    jsonWriter.endArray();
    jsonWriter.name("literals");
    jsonWriter.beginArray();
    jsonWriter.beginObject();
    jsonWriter.name("literal");
    jsonWriter.beginArray();
    jsonWriter.value("A");
    jsonWriter.value("B");
    jsonWriter.value("C");
    jsonWriter.value("D");
    jsonWriter.endArray();
    jsonWriter.endObject();
    jsonWriter.endArray();
    jsonWriter.endObject();
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}finally{
    try {
        jsonWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the file. Thanks for your recent reply.

Comment: Still `"literals":[{"literal":"A", "B", "C", "D"}]` is not valid. I think you wanted to do this: `"literals":[{"literal":["A", "B", "C", "D"]}]` - i.e. `literals` is an object that contain single member named `literal` and it is a `List`. Is that correct assumption?

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for your assistance. It is very much appreciated. Actually I have a big amount of data. I will try to manage it now with your solution. Once again, thank you very much.